# How to update an Android app widget every minute

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager

**Note**: I know this question has been asked before however the few solutions posted are either out of date and/or do not work for me

Hi, I'm trying to make a clock app widget (a countdown clock) which will display a list of different countdown duration for Android, however I'm running into trouble trying to make it update once every minute. I have tried using `AlarmManager` however it's not working for some reason.

Here's everything I have:

**EventWidget.kt**

```
/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
class EventWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    class UpdateTimeService : Service() {

        private val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)
        }

        private val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) = update(context)
        }


        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
        }

        override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }

        override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

            if (intent != null && UPDATE_TIME == intent.action) update(this)

            return START_STICKY
        }

        companion object {
            const val UPDATE_TIME = "com.richardrobinson.countdown2.action.UPDATE_TIME"
        }

    }

    private lateinit var pending: PendingIntent

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        appWidgetIds.forEach {
            val intent = Intent(context, EventWidgetService::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, it)
                data = Uri.parse(toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))
            }

            val rv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.event_widget).apply {
                setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listView, intent)
                setEmptyView(R.id.listView, R.id.emptyView)
            }

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(it, rv)
        }

        update(context)

        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.listView)

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
        super.onEnabled(context)
        val pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, Intent(context, UpdateTimeService::class.java), 0)

        val interval: Long = 1000 * 60

        (context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager).apply {
            cancel(pending)
            setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pending)
        }

        update(context)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        update(context)
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}

fun update(context: Context) {
    val rv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.event_widget).apply {
        setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listView, Intent(context, EventWidgetService::class.java))
        setEmptyView(R.id.listView, R.id.emptyView)
    }

    val component = ComponentName(context, EventWidget::class.java)

    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).apply {
        updateAppWidget(component, rv)

        val ids = getAppWidgetIds(component)
        ids.forEach { updateAppWidget(it, rv) }

        notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(ids, R.id.listView)
    }

}
```

**EventWidgetService.kt**

```
class EventWidgetService : RemoteViewsService() {
    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent): RemoteViewsFactory =
            EventRemoteViewsFactory(this.applicationContext, intent)
}

class EventRemoteViewsFactory(private val context: Context, intent: Intent) : RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private val prefsName = "FlutterSharedPreferences"

    override fun onCreate() {
        MiniModel.initialize(context.getSharedPreferences(prefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
    }

    override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.id.emptyView)

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean = true

    @ExperimentalTime
    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        return RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_item).apply {
            val event = MiniModel.events[position]
            val remaining = event.secondsRemaining.inSeconds / (event.end.epochSecond - event.start.epochSecond).toDouble()

            setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 100, (remaining * 100).toInt(), false)

            setTextViewText(R.id.item_text, event.title)

            setTextViewText(R.id.details_text, "whatever")
        }
    }


    override fun getCount(): Int = MiniModel.events.count()

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int = 1

    override fun onDestroy() {
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.richardrobinson.countdown2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Hourglass">
        <receiver android:name=".EventWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/event_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!--
                 This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme).
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".EventWidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
        <service android:name=".EventWidget$UpdateTimeService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.richardrobinson.countdown2.action.UPDATE_TIME"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

// Try out with timer :

```
private Timer myTimer = new Timer(); 
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // use runOnUiThread(Runnable action)
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // do your task
        }
    });
}
}, timeInterval);
```